# Hypersill Java decrypted task

Tags: java, string, loops, char

I'm trying to do Encrypted- Decrypted task on HyperSkill.

Task:
Write a program that reads three lines from the standard input: a target operation (enc - encryption, dec - decryption), a message or a cyphertext, and a key to encrypt/decrypt messages. All non-letter characters must be encrypted as well as regular letters.

I have a problem with decrypted part.

I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:709)
    at encryptdecrypt.Main.dec(Main.java:63)
    at encryptdecrypt.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

What am I doing wrong?

My Code:

```
package encryptdecrypt;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What to do?");
        String target = scanner.nextLine();
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        int key = scanner.nextInt();

        if (target.equals("enc")) {
            enc(input, key);
        } else if (target.equals("dec")) {
            dec(input, key);
        }

    }

    public static String enc(String input, int key) {

        String output = "";
        String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";


        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            String inputCharacter = Character.toString(input.charAt(i));

            if (!alphabet.contains(inputCharacter)) {
                output += inputCharacter;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < alphabet.length(); j++) {
                String alphabetCharacter = Character.toString(alphabet.charAt(j));
                String decryptedCharacter = Character.toString(alphabet.charAt((j + key) % alphabet.length()));

                if (inputCharacter.equals(alphabetCharacter)) {
                    output += decryptedCharacter;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(output);
        return output;
    }

    public static String dec(String input, int key) {

        String encrypted = "";
        String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";


        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            String decryptedCharacter = Character.toString(input.charAt(i));

            if (!alphabet.contains(decryptedCharacter)) {
                input += decryptedCharacter;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < alphabet.length(); j++) {
                char alphabetCharacter = alphabet.charAt(j);
                String encryptedCharacter = Character.toString(alphabet.charAt((j - key) % alphabet.length()));

                if (encryptedCharacter.equals(alphabetCharacter)) {
                    encrypted += encryptedCharacter;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(encrypted);
        return encrypted;
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments cannot contain that content: `(-1) % 5 == -1`

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you start by writing tests for your code.

If you read the error message it actually tells you what your issue is "String index out of range: -1"

This is most likely due to the line containing

```
(j - key) % alphabet.length()
```

since any value other than 0 for key will result in a negative number which per the javadoc on charAt

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index argument is negative or not less than the length of this string.
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help you prevent index at charAt(j - key) from being negative:

```
if (key > j) {
    j += alphabet.length();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to reverse your alphabet and use (j + key)